# greenplum initialization failed

Tags: greenplum

When I tried to initialize Greenplum I got the following error

> ```
> 20180408:23:21:02:017614 gpstop:datanode3:root-[INFO]:-Starting gpstop with args: 
> 20180408:23:21:02:017614 gpstop:datanode3:root-[INFO]:-Gathering information and validating the environment...
> 20180408:23:21:02:017614 gpstop:datanode3:root-[ERROR]:-gpstop error: postmaster.pid file does not exist.  is Greenplum instance already stopped?
> ```

also when i tried to check gpstate command i got the following error

> ```
> 20180408:23:21:48:017711 gpstate:datanode3:root-[INFO]:-Starting gpstate with args: 
> 20180408:23:21:48:017711 gpstate:datanode3:root-[INFO]:-local Greenplum Version: 'postgres (Greenplum Database) 5.7.0 build f7c6eb5-oss'
> 20180408:23:21:48:017711 gpstate:datanode3:root-[CRITICAL]:-gpstate failed. (Reason='could not connect to server: Connection refused
> ```

I also did the configuration an add a permission on PostgreSQL.conf, but the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You have pasted the output of gpstop.

> gpstop error: postmaster.pid file does not exist.  is Greenplum
>   instance already stopped?

Which means that the database is not running.